# change button image in viewdidload function

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to change the button image in viewdidload/viewwillappear function. If possible then how the particular button(if I have 2 buttons) will identify in these function.

Comment: can you post  ur code where u r creating your button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(275, 8, 40.0, 40.0);
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"button_home.png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(goHome) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:button];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

Here I have created the button programmatically!

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use to update the image of weather button in my viewDidLoad:

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:iconURL]]] retain];
if (img != nil) 
{ 
    [weatherButton setImage:img forState:normal];
    img = nil; 
}
```

I am getting the image from a URL. Hope this helps.

Comment: shouldn't it be [weatherButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: It is a button, but how we will get this in viewdidload function without sender. I have created button in IB.

Comment: u can simply add a tag to ur button

Comment: write, UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

Comment: i have used 1 as tag u can use anynumber.u can chnage this btn image

Comment: @swastik: can you please provide me code to identify a button on the basis of tag in viewdidload function.

Comment: UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

Comment: u need to set tag for ur btn whereever u r creating it

Comment: @swastik: you r from which city and how much exp do u have in iphone ?

Comment: Great, I m frm satna(M.P.) but working in kolkata, an very new in iPhone.

Comment: @swastik: can u give me your any contact(mail id) for any doubt or query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, u can use this

```
[button setImage:image forState:state];
```